# Does anyone know of a good pre-existing javascript date range drop-down?

Tags: javascript, date, drop-down-menu, date-range

I'm looking for a javascript drop-down for a date range that allows the user to select start and end dates from a single form field, similar to what exists in the Google Analytics UI.

I've found a lot of pre-existing javascript for two separate form fields, or for using a calendar to choose a single date, but nothing that accomplishes what the Google Analytics date range selector does.  Does anyone know of a good pre-built tool that does this, or am I stuck building it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ExtJs extensions that allow date ranges to be selected.

http://extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=22473
http://extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=20597

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could check out [jQuery](http://jquery.com), and the UI library which provides the DatePicker control:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

I use this one:

http://www.frequency-decoder.com/2006/10/02/unobtrusive-date-picker-widgit-update/

> An attempt at writing a datePicker
>   (calendar) that is accessible using
>   the keyboard, requires no embedded
>   JavaScript blocks, uses no pop-up
>   windows and is suitable for use within
>   documents served as
>   application/xhtml+xml. A quick feature
>   list…
>
> ```
> * Fully keyboard accessible
> * Multiple date formats and date dividers supported
> * Unobtrusive and nameSpace friendly
> * Fully skinnable with CSS
> * Both upper and lower date limits can be set
> * Certain days of the week can be disabled
> * Certain, dates can be disabled/enabled (and wildcards used
> ```
>
> to stipulate the dates in question)
>       * Includes “smart” localisation (16 languages currently available)
>       * Bespoke days of the week can be highlighted
>       * Works with single text inputs, split text inputs or select lists
>       * It’s free to use, even commercially (Released under a CC
>   share-alike license)